# Как добавить ссылкой дополнительный параметр в GET запрос в url, чтобы не удалить другие параметры

Tags: php, битрикс, get

В битриксе умный фильтр работает через GET запросы например

```
/index.php?bitrix_include_areas=Y&set_filter=1&filter_P1_MIN=&filter_P1_MAX=
```

Сортировка работает тоже через GET параметр sort, и если я нажимаю на ссылку или отправляю форму методом гет с нужным параметром то параметры фильтра затираются

`/telefony/index.php?sort=priced`

Мне нужен такой результат чтобы фильтр и  сортировка были вместе, нашёл такое решение:

`<li><a href="?<?= http_build_query(array_merge(['sort' => 'priced'], $_GET)); ?>">Цене (сначала дорогие)</a></li>`

если его выбрать все работает нормально гет запросы соединяются результат:

```
/telefony/index.php?sort=priced&set_filter=1&filter_P1_MIN=&filter_P1_MAX=&filter_17067_3033739923=Y
```

но допустим я хочу сортировать не по дорогой цене
а по дешевой тут такая же ссылка

`<li><a href="?<?= http_build_query(array_merge(['sort' => 'pricea'], $_GET)); ?>">Цене (сначала дешевые</a></li>`

При нажатии параметр sort не меняется и ссылка остается такой же

/`telefony/index.phpsort=priced&set_filter=1&filter_P1_MIN=&filter_P1_MAX=&filter_17067_3033739923=Y`

не могу понять как поменять параметр sort в get запросе чтобы остальные параметры сохранились

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**array_merge** — Сливает один или большее количество массивов

Если входные массивы имеют одинаковые строковые ключи, тогда каждое последующее значение будет заменять предыдущее.

Поменяйте местами параметры:

```
array_merge($_GET, ['sort' => 'pricea'])
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, поменял местами параметы,теперь меняет значение ключа sort